# Can an arcing switch damage the breaker or cause a fire?

Tags: electrical, switch, circuit-breaker

I live in a 1980s  mobile home with light switches and breakers as in the picture. If the switch is arcing or if the switch is held between on/off for a few seconds can this damage the breaker? The switch is a self contained type.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The arcing would be at the switch. I don't see how it could damage the breaker, but it sure could damage the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Arcing is not a good thing for the switch but it won't damage a standard circuit breaker. If the switch contacts are held at a point where they arc the arc starts damaging the contacts. With a older possibly Mercury switch where there is a glass tube with Mercury the arcing if held to the point the mercury vaporizes I have seen the glass tube fracture so a new switch was needed.