# Switch Arcing Mobile Home

Tags: lighting

Hi I live in a mobile home also late 80s/early 90s I have a few light switches that makes a sizzling sound at times they are the self contained type switch!

What is occurring during arcing in a switch? is this any different then an arc fault such as nipped/cut cable in the wall do I need arc fault breakers?

Answer (score 2):

Any time you hear that sound, proceed with the utmost caution, there's an excellent chance there's an issue that's a fire hazard.  It might be better to get an electrician to look at this ASAP rather than chipping away at it DIY.

I'd be more concerned about the arcing generating heat at the arc and damaging your wiring and possibly starting a fire than the arcs damaging your breakers.

Most of the self-contained switches I've seen are pretty sketchy quality.  If the sound is really coming from the switches, just replace them, but look for any evidence of damage to the wiring from the heat generated by the arcing.

Arc fault protection certainly wouldn't hurt, you may be able to add it without too much disruption, or it might be a big project.  But you don't want to rely too much on arc fault detection, it may be helpful but it's certainly not perfect - you want to address any issues with the wiring ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a few switches that were connected using the backstabs instead of the screw terminals. Turn off the breakers and replace the switches   with new ones. Don't use the old ones but make sure to use the screw terminals. Backstabs are bad news. check the wiring at the switch locations for any burn marks or melted insulation. The breakers shouldn't really be affected by this as it's down line and a small load. By the way, what's the load on those switches?

Comment: You mean since it's down the line then the arcing in the switch is not at the breaker? arcing or arcing faults heat is not at the breaker is that correct?

Comment: The load is just over head lights the breaker is a double 15 amp on a single pole/bus the breaker is a bd1515 type

Comment: The self-contained switches that are often used in mobile homes usually use and insulation - displacement type connections.  I don't have much experience with them but I think they are about as reliable as backstabs - that is, not very reliable at all.  See very similar question https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/160219/can-an-arcing-switch-damage-the-breaker-or-cause-a-fire